# We noticed that your Google Cloud Project has open project firewalls

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firewall, firebase-security, ports

I got an email from: saying: (console.cloud.google.com)

**We noticed that your Google Cloud Project has open project firewalls. This could make your instance vulnerable to compromises since anyone on the internet can access and establish a connection to the instance.
The following project has open firewalls:

    Playchat (ID: playchat-4cc1d)

Google Cloud Platform provides the flexibility for you to configure your project to your specific needs. We recommend updating your settings to only allow access to the ports that your project requires.**

I get a bit confused because in the Firebase console database i have the basic rule at: (console.firebase.google.com)

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

I just started to learn Firebase and asking if someone can explain this? If I have this rules `".read": "auth != null",` then why do i get this warning?

Comment: That email seems unrelated to your Firebase Database security rules.

Comment: btw, This is about the [playchat](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible#creating-project) tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There s 2 separate things:
1) Accessing the firebase realtime data base.
2) Accessing the instance that stores runs the application.

Your firebase database indeed blocks unauthenticated users,but your server is still vulnerable to compromises, for example someone can connect to your server and add or update the code.

Comment: Do you mean I should create a firewall ip address rule that only allow my developer pc, from where I upload the backend-web-app code? Im completely new to this please elaborate?

Comment: Yes, You should allow ssh and upload  to your server only from your dev machine source IP address.

Comment: I see I have the **default-allow-ssh**. I will modify it. I use a VPN services and dont have static ip. Do you think using the instance tag is the way to go?

Comment: If you use road warrior VPN you can limit access only to the internal address range of the private network. But if  your PC is behind NAT (much more common) I think you shouldn't modify the ssh firewall rule, nad just ignore the warning.

Comment: I have the VyprVPN installed on my Asus ROG GL752 laptop herre in Sweden, and i get internet from my mobile phone (hotspot NAT ) i think. By default the mobile internet provider dont give me static ip. Can you give me any concrete how to secure my playchat-4cc1d?

Comment: Since you don't have static IP , I can't see any way to protect the service by updating the firewall, sorry.

Comment: ok i get it thanks. I will use the [PureVpn static ip](https://www.purevpn.com/dedicated-ip.php) so it will work. It's very strange that it works like this when I have to login to Firebase developer with my pc to work with my project, and then the Firewall doesn't use this logged in credentials, but instead I have to explicitly set an ip address to the same pc.