# Can the GAE Servlet code be accessest by anyone

Tags: google-app-engine, firewall

I just when trough [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio) about Using

> Firebase and App Engine Standard Environment in an Android App

It was grate but I wonder now can anyone upload and replace my servlet code. Like do I need to set up some firewall somewhere. I read [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#top_of_page) 
 about

> Using Networks and Firewalls

but I cannot see any hands-on how to apply this, it´s really advanced and if someone could break it down, what I need to do to only allow me to access the code.

I´m a bit new to this but when working with [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible#creating-project)

> Build an Android App Using Firebase and the App Engine Flexible
>   Environment

I got this email from CloudPlatform-noreply saying I must maintain a Firewalls :

> Dear Developer, We noticed that your Google Cloud Project has open
>   project firewalls. This could make your instance vulnerable to
>   compromises since anyone on the internet can access and establish a
>   connection to the instance. The following project has open firewalls:
>     Playchat (ID: playchat-4cc1d) Google Cloud Platform provides the
>   flexibility for you to configure your project to your specific needs.
>   We recommend updating your settings to only allow access to the ports
>   that your project requires. You can review your project's settings by
>   inspecting the output of gcloud compute firewall-rules or by visiting
>   the firewall settings page on the GCP Console. Learn more about using
>   firewalls and secure connections to VM instances.

What do I need to be afraid of here - what does "since anyone on the internet can access and establish a connection to the instance." really mean?

I want my Firebase signed in users to be able to access only

Comment: Only you and list of admins specified by you are able to upload new Appengine app versions. You don't need to do anything specific for that protection

Comment: how would you explain this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922883/we-noticed-that-your-google-cloud-project-has-open-project-firewalls) that say the opposite

Comment: it says _can access and establish a connection to the instance_, but you're asking how to protect source code, right? I'm stating that source code and admin console is accessible by admins only

Answer (score 0):

**Source code deployment**
The only people that can deploy source code to your app are ones that you've given access to in the [IAM permissions pages in the Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project). People there need Owner or have the specific role of "App Engine Admin" or "App Engine Deployer".

**Connecting to your instances**
If you are using the App Engine standard environment there are **no** virtual machine instances. The standard environment is purely a platform as a service, not your typical hosting environment with servers.

If you are using the App Engine flexible environment, your code does run on virtual machine instances. However, those instances by default are locked down. You can [enable SSH for debugging purposes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/debugging-an-instance). These connections however use the tokens via your authorized gcloud installation to connect. All this is just to say, that by default your instances are locked down and even in the debug mode they are still pretty secure.

Overall, your code is secure by default. Protecting your resources is actually probably more about protecting your Gmail account and thus its connected resources like your Cloud Platform projects. Protect your account with two-factor authentication, don't give people more access to your project than they require, and lastly don't enable debugging unless you need it and even then close it down when you're done.